# Angular 2 - change neighbor input variable on input variable change

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-components, angular2-inputs

I want to perform some operations when input parameters are being changed. Lets say I have a DatePicker component that has a `type` input variable, and I want to perform some actions with another `date` variable when type is being changed. How to do that?

```
export class DatePicker {

    @Input()
    date: Date;

    @Output()
    dateChange = new EventEmitter();

    @Input()
    set type(type: string) {
        if (type === "today") {
            this.date = new Date();
            this.dateChange(this.date); // because of this change change detector will throw error
        }
    }

}
```

Error: **Expression has changed after it was checked.**

Comment: I suggest you make the first `@Input() date: any;` and then process the Input variable

Comment: `this.dateChange(this.date);` should be `this.dateChange.emit(this.date);` (missing `emit`)

Comment: you've a temporal coupling here that should be avoided. it is required that `date` is set before `type`. Either merge both into a single `date: Date | string` or put them in an object. Even `dateChange` should have a listener already in-place, which sounds like it is better to find a different approach.

Comment: there are lot of use cases when you have to do something when input changes, more less coupled then this example. But you can't do anything and that is a problem. Also [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7782) discussion related to this issue

Answer (score -3):

**update**

Angular2 causes this error when it looks like change detection itself has side effects that causes model change which usually indicates a bug or a design flaw that causes Angular2 applications to work inefficiently.

To **hide** such an issue you can just enable `prodMode`.

A workaround for model changes in lifecycle methods call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` to make it explicit that this model change is intentional

```
export class DatePicker {

    constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    @Input()
    date: Date;

    @Output()
    dateChange = new EventEmitter();

    @Input()
    set type(type: string) {
        if (type === "today") {
            this.date = new Date();
            this.dateChange(this.date); 
            this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**original**

You can either use `setTimeout()`
`setTimeout()` is a sledgehammer method because it causes a change detection cycle for the whole application.

```
@Input()
set type(type: string) {
    if (type === "today") {
        this.date = new Date();
        setTimeout(() => this.dateChange(this.date)); 
    }
}
```

This is necessary when `type` is updated by change detection because Angular2 doesn't like when change detection causes changes.

Another way is to use `ngOnChanges()` but this is also called by change detection and also needs the `setTimeout()` Workaround

```
export class DatePicker implements OnChanges {

    @Input()
    date: Date;

    @Output()
    dateChange = new EventEmitter();

    @Input()
    set type:string;

    ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges) {
      if(changes['type']) {
        if (type === "today") {
            this.date = new Date();
            setTimeout(() => this.dateChange(this.date));
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The difference between these two approaches is that the first executes the code for every change, the last only for changes caused by bindings.

Comment: using setTimeout looks like a monkey patch. Same monkey patch we were using in angular1 with setTimeout and apply. We need something better

Comment: I heard that quite a few times about `setTimeout()`. I don't see an issue with `setTimeout()` as long as other code doesn't depend on a specific time to be passed or not yet have to be passed. All it does is to schedule the change to happen after the current change detection cycle is completed and invoke another change detection after the change.

Comment: You can try injecting `private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef` and call `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` after `this.dateChange(this.date)`

Comment: i think it was the first solution I tried when I had this problem, not sure now, need to check, but as I remember it caused errors too

Comment: setTimeout can't be a solution to a synchronous task.

Comment: @Werlang what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean introducing asynchronicity in a perfectly synchronous sequence is a bad smell. It is not usual that you don't know why a `setTimeout()` works in such cases. It may work now, but you'll never know for how long. That's why you heard about this quite a few times.

Comment: It has a bad reputation, I know why, but many people who argue it's bad seem not to have any idea why they think it's bad. I think in this case where change detection causes a change it's a good idea to use it. It allows the current change detection to complete before another change happens. This makes it easier to reason about the program and makes it **more** reliable, not less.

Comment: I disagree it makes it easier to reason about. An error pops out on my screen, I won't try to just circunvent it.

Comment: Any better ideas for the concrete case?

Comment: and as I put as a comment in the question, there's a design issue going on here first and foremost

Comment: I guess you are right about that but the question doesn't provide enough context.